# Sum of repeating values in successive rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
id col1 col2 col3
10  1          3
9   1    2     3
8        2     3
7        2     3
6   1    2    
5              3
```

Each column has one value only or null. Eg. Col1 has 1 or empty. Col2 has 2 or empty.

I'd like to get the sum of repeating values only between two successive rows.
so the result would look like this:

I need to get the sum of total repeating values in each row.

```
id col1 col2 col3   Count
10  1          3     2    (shows the repeating values between id10 & id9 rows)
9   1    2     3     2    (shows the repeating values between id9 & id8 rows)
8        2     3     1
7        2           1
6   1    2           0
5              3
```

I googled and tried some queries I found on the web but couldn't get the right result. Thanks in advance for your help.

To further clarify, for example:
id10 row has (1,,3) and id9 row has (1,2,3). so there is two values repeating. so count is 2.

Comment: I can't work out what your Count is actually showing...

Comment: Which row is considered "successive"?

Comment: How come id 9 doesn't have a count of 3? I don't understand your expected output and how you came to it

Comment: Count shows the count of repeating values in three columns. so first row there is 2 values repeat.

Comment: for example, 10 and 9 are successive. 9 and 8. 8 and 7 etc.

Comment: What? The first row (id 10) has 2 columns with data, different data, what part of that row is "repeated"? Why does the first row have a count of 2?

Comment: id9 and id8 have two values in common (2,3). so the count is 2.

Comment: I mean, i compare two following ids (like id10 and id9) and then the values in each column.

Comment: I have to wonder what your use case is for this. I wouldn't do this in SQL, try doing it in PHP.

Comment: Is it the case that the values for col1 are always either null or 1? Likewise for columns 2 and 3?

Comment: yes, col1 is either 1 or null, col2 is either 2 or null, col3 is either 3 or null.

Comment: Why for id = 8 the count = 1?

Comment: can one row have the same value ? i mean in one row , you can have 1,1,1  or 1,1,2?

Comment: @forpas, count=1 shows the count of comparison between id8 and i7.

Comment: Your sample data for id=7 and the expected results are different.

Comment: no. each column can have one value or null. so there can't be same values in all columns in the same row. so there won't be 1,1,1, or 1,1,2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the ids are consecutive and there are no gaps, you can do it with a self join:

```
select 
  t.*,
  coalesce((t.col1 = tt.col1), 0) + 
  coalesce((t.col2 = tt.col2), 0) + 
  coalesce((t.col3 = tt.col3), 0) count
from tablename t left join tablename tt
on tt.id = t.id - 1
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eRuSgkvBejFd9rAf7K7hxL/0).
Results:

```
| id  | col1 | col2 | col3 | count |
| --- | ---- | ---- | ---- | ----- |
| 10  | 1    |      | 3    | 2     |
| 9   | 1    | 2    | 3    | 2     |
| 8   |      | 2    | 3    | 1     |
| 7   |      | 2    |      | 1     |
| 6   | 1    | 2    |      | 0     |
| 5   |      |      | 3    | 0     |
```

Comment: t is the 1st alias of tablename.

Answer (score 2):

And if there are gaps...

```
SELECT a.id 
     , a.col1 
     , a.col2 
     , a.col3 
     , COALESCE(a.col1 = b.col1,0) + COALESCE(a.col2 = b.col2,0) + COALESCE(a.col3 = b.col3,0) n 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , MIN(y.id) y_id 
         FROM my_table x 
         JOIN my_table y 
           ON y.id > x.id 
        GROUP 
           BY x.id
      ) a 
   LEFT
   JOIN my_table b 
     ON b.id = a.y_id;
```

Were you to restructure your schema, then you could do something like this instead...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL 
,val INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(id,val)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(10,1),
(10,3),
( 9,1),
( 9,2),
( 9,3),
( 8,2),
( 8,3),
( 7,2),
( 7,3),
( 6,1),
( 6,2),
( 5,3); 

SELECT a.id
     , COUNT(b.id) total 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , MIN(y.id) next 
         FROM my_table x 
         JOIN my_table y 
           ON y.id > x.id 
        GROUP 
           BY x.id
            , x.val
     ) a 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table b 
    ON b.id = a.next 
   AND b.val = a.val 
 GROUP 
    BY a.id;
+----+-------+
| id | total |
+----+-------+
|  5 |     0 |
|  6 |     1 |
|  7 |     2 |
|  8 |     2 |
|  9 |     2 |
+----+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
select t1_ID, t1_col1,t1_col2,t1_col3, count
  from
(
select t1.id as t1_ID, t1.col1 as t1_col1,t1.col2 as t1_col2,t1.col3 as t1_col3, t2.*,
       case when t1.col1 = t2.col1 then 1 else 0 end +
       case when t1.col2 = t2.col2 then 1 else 0 end +
       case when t1.col3 = t2.col3 then 1 else 0 end as count
  from tab t1
  left join tab t2 
    on t1.id = t2.id + 1
 order by t1.id
) t3
order by t1_ID desc;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=ca2f77159fe331afa9e2a2c35ad3830d)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

If there are gaps between `id` values for the next row, you could have [user defined variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) to explicitly assign values to rows in their natural ordering in the table. Rest logic remains the same as already answered. You would do an inner join between current row number and next row number to get the `col1`,`col2` and `col3` values and use [coalesce](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) for computation of `count`.

```
select derived_1.*,
  coalesce((derived_1.col1 = derived_2.col1), 0) + 
  coalesce((derived_1.col2 = derived_2.col2), 0) + 
  coalesce((derived_1.col3 = derived_2.col3), 0) count
from (
        select @row := @row + 1 as row_number,t1.*
        from tablename t1,(select @row := 0) d1
      ) derived_1
left join (
       select *
       from (
             select @row2 := @row2 + 1 as row_number,t2.*
             from tablename t2,(select @row2 := 0) d2
            ) d3
        ) derived_2
on derived_1.row_number + 1 = derived_2.row_number;
```

**Demo:** https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wAzb67zSEfbZKg5RywQvC8/1